# GZIP corruption with big files?

Tags: linux, bash, gzip

I came across a weird behavior:

gzip v1.5 - Fedora r18

A file

```
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 3892576256 Apr 28 11:29 vm.qcow2
```

Initial checksum:

```
md5sum vm.qow2
954c5461468d68daed3cef6a7b66bd8f vm.qcow2
```

If I gzip as below:

```
gzip -c vm.qcow2 > a.qcow2.gz
gzip -c vm.qcow2 > folder/b.qcow2.gz
```

md5sum the gz

```
md5sum a.qow2.gz
182e56c19881028be94d6b5d72334620 a.qow2.gz
md5sum b.qow2.gz
4a7d141e8aed62a4935880c0b9067c8f b.qow2.gz
```

There is a mismatch, maybe due to timestamp... but it's not finished

unzip the gzs and md5sum the result

```
gunzip a.qow2.gz
md5sum a.qow2
954c5461468d68daed3cef6a7b66bd8f a.qcow2
```

Which is good

```
gunzip b.qow2.gz
md5sum b.qow2
ca1c872ab277d3f7d473cacf0d140012 b.qcow2
```

which is wrong...

gz and unzipped file have the same size, only contents differs. (hard to diff due to size).

Why adding a folder to destination corrupt the original file ?

Thank you :p

Comment: Did you leave out the cd folder, or folder/ prefix to the second gunzip, or do you have a different b.qow file in the current directory?

Comment: The question I'd be asking myself is "Why did the timestamp of vm.qcow2 change?" Is it possible that some other process was modifying vm.qcow2 while the zipping was going on?